# Nativescript Angular build APK with PROD environment is not working

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm running `tns build android --env.production`

At the end, the APK builded is using my `environment.ts` file instead of `environment.prod.ts`

I didn't find any error

```
@angular/core: 8.2.0
 nativescript-angular: 8.21.0
 nativescript-dev-webpack: 1.5.0
 @ngtools/webpack: 8.2.0
```

Why ?

Comment: Did you try `tns build android --bundle --env.environment="prod"`?

Comment: This doesn't work too

Comment: Can you check this article: https://medium.com/@derekfong/nativescript-angular-setup-environment-ts-for-different-environments-631b4c5219b6

Comment: I modified webpack.config.js as the tutorial, and tryied `tns build android --bundle --env.environment="prod"`, my app is still using environment.ts instead of environment.prod.ts

Answer (score 0):

when you create the project with tns there is also a angulat.json file created.
Check if the configuration.production.fileReplacements is set right.
Then run the build again.

use strg+f to find the line where it says "configurations"

```
 "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
```